# How to store an ArrayList or a HashMap to a file or in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, json, file, sharedpreferences

I have searched, but haven't been able to find a proper solution for my problem.
I am receiving data from a server and displaying it, I want this data to be stored locally, preferably in `SharedPreferences` or a file
If there is Internet access, the data should be stored and updated.
If there is no Internet access this data should be displayed.

Below is my code

```
package com.timetable;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MondayTimeTable_TE_Elex extends ListActivity {
    // JSON Node names
    private static String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static String TAG_NAME = "name";
    String FILENAME = "monday_te_elex_file";
    FileInputStream fis;

    ListView listViewItem;
    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray monday_te_elex = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monday_time_table_te_elex);

        new PlaceOrder().execute();
        listViewItem = getListView();

    }

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> categoriesList;

    class PlaceOrder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // Example for param :
            // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", 1));
            inputStream = Request.setHttpRequest(
                    "http://asimmerchant.hostoi.com/TE/Elex/Monday/monday_te_elex.php",
                    nameValuePairs);

            // Hashmap for ListView
            categoriesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            if (inputStream != null) {
                result = StringResponse.convertResponseToString(inputStream);
                result = result.trim();
            }

            if (result == null || result.equals("null")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid request");

            } else {

                try {
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    JSONObject json_data = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        try {
                            String id = json_data.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String name = json_data.getString(TAG_NAME);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                            categoriesList.add(map);

                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MondayTimeTable_TE_Elex.this,
                    categoriesList, R.layout.list, new String[] { TAG_NAME},
                    new int[] { R.id.name });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            /**
             * Selecting single ListView item
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` can't store only primitive type, so you can't use it to store a `Collection`. You could use serialization to write it on your internal storage, but it can get tricky. I would suggest you to store the `JSONObject`/`JSONArray` (result is your case) in the `SharedPreferences` as `String`.

Comment: I store jarray in SharedPreference?

Comment: result more than jArray. Remember that jArray.toString() is equal to result

Comment: what method should i use to store result?

Comment: i was able to store 'result' using putString and retrieve using getString, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

According to me there are two ways to achieve it.
if you want to store a particular object.

1. You need to convert your object into string format and write it into plain text file and read later.That is even faster from reading Json.
2. You can serialize the object into JSON/Strings form and use sharedPreferences to store it.you can use Gson library for it.